# React TS: wait for props before calling function with props as arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React through functional components. One of my components has props that are passed by its parent components, like:

```
const About = () => {
  const { data } = useFetch('About');

  return (
    <div>
      {data && (
        <div>
          <Title title={data.custom_title} />
          <Card
            text={data.body}
          >
            <Skills skills={data.skills} columns={data.n_skills_columns} />
          </Card>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

These props are used in a function to manipulate the prop data before rendering it, such as:

```
const Skills: FC<SkillsProps> = ({ skills, columns }): JSX.Element => {
  const skillsTable = sliceArray(skills, columns);
  return (
    <div>
      skillsTable.map(...)
    </div>
  );
};
```

Within the `Skills` component, the props contain data when I console.log the data with an useEffect hook, nevertheless `sliceArray()` complains that its arguments are `undefined`.

What I already tried:

```
const Skills: FC<SkillsProps> = ({ skills_, columns_ }): JSX.Element => {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSkills(skills_);
    setColumns(columns_);
  }, []);

  const skillsTable = sliceArray(skills, columns);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where do the `skills` and `columns` props come from? How do you pass them to the `Skills` component?

Comment: I added the parent component to the question so you can see how props are passed

Comment: Is `useFetch` a custom hook or from a library like `react-query`?

Comment: It's a custom hook, which works in other components

Comment: Did you make sure that `data` is always either a falsy (e.g. `undefined`) or an object with the keys `skills` and `n_skills_columns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add default values to the destructured props. There's no need for a `useEffect` or `useState` (unless you're modifying these values somehow in your `Skills` component).

```
const Skills: FC<SkillsProps> = ({ skills = [], columns = 1 }) => {
  const skillsTable = sliceArray(skills, columns);

  return ...;
}
```

If you don't want to render the `Skills` component at all before `skills_` and `columns_` are loaded, then add a loading indicator in the parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const skills = ...;
  if (!skills) return <>Loading skills...</>;
  return <Skills skills={skills} />;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.